# get only the name of the selected input file

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get only the name of the selected file using this regex :

```
var regex = /.*(\/|\\)/;
```

but it only works in some cases, you can find the full example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mQVC/109/) :

```
var regex = /.*(\/|\\)/;

var path1 = 'C:\fakepath\filename.doc'.replace(regex, ''),
    path2 = 'C:\\fakepath\\filename.doc'.replace(regex, ''),
    path3 = '/var/fakepath/filename.doc'.replace(regex, '');
```

How can solve this ?

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of output you are expecting for a given input? An example would be great.

Comment: You can try [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) wich is a great regex tester.

Comment: OP, please never just link to your code, write the relevant part in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't where you think it is.

Your problem is in writing [your literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).

`'C:\fakepath\filename.doc'` doesn't make the `\` character but the `\f` one (form feed).

This being said, don't use `replace` when you want to extract a string, but `match`, so that you can define what you want instead of what you don't want:

```
var regex = /[^\/\\]+$/;

var path1 = 'C:\\fakepath\\filename.doc'.match(regex)[0],
    path2 = 'C:\\fakepath\\filename.doc'.match(regex)[0],
    path3 = '/var/fakepath/filename.doc'.match(regex)[0];
```